# tooltip cortada pela div

Tags: html, css, div, tooltip

Bom dia pessoal. Estou tentando criar um tooltip somente com css num painel lateral à direita da pagina. Nesse painel aparece uma lista de usuários e cada tooltip apresenta um breve perfil, bastante semelhante à lista de usuário do facebook em que aparece uma tooltip com foto e informações do usuário com o mouseover. Já consegui fazer o tooltip e tudo mais, no entanto, quando uso a propriedade overflow o tooltip acaba cortado pela div parent; o fato é que a lista de usuários é grande e precisa de um scroll. Já pesquisei em todo lugar e não encontrei uma solução. Alguém poderia me ajudar como resolver esse problema?

```css
*{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
html, body{background:#000;overflow:hidden;}
.painel
{
    width:15%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:80px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow: auto; /*só funciona com hidden */
    min-width:200px;
    background: blue;
}

#users_online ul{list-style-type:none;}
#users_online
{
    padding-left:5px;
    background: red;
}
#users_online ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-right:0;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#users_online ul li:hover{border-color:#999; background:linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #000 160%);}
#users_online ul li a{text-decoration:none; float:left; width:70%; margin-left:10px;font-size:14px;color:#999;line-height:40px;}
#users_online ul li a .nome_titulo{line-height:20px;}
#users_online ul li a .nome_dados{font-size:12px;line-height:20px;}
#users_online ul li a p span.tipo_usuario{font-size:12px;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;}
#users_online ul li a:hover{color:#000;}

.imgSmall
{
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.imgSmall img{width:100%; height:100%;}

.tooltip_usuario
{
    position:absolute;
}
a.tooltip_usuario span.toolinfo:hover{text-decoration:none;color:rgb(139,29,30);}
a.tooltip_usuario span.toolinfo{font-size:14px;display:none;padding:10px 10px;margin-top:-40px;margin-left:-350px;width:310px;line-height:15px;}
a.tooltip_usuario:hover span.toolinfo{display:inline;position:absolute;border:1px solid #000;background:#CCC;color:#000;z-index:1;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="painel"> 
    <aside id="users_online">
        <ul>
            <?php for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++): ?>
            <li id="<?php echo $i ?>">
                <div class="imgSmall"><img src="fotos/" border="0" /></div>
                <a href="#" class="tooltip_usuario">     
                    <p class="nome_titulo">Nome Teste</p><p class="nome_dados"><span class="tipo_usuario">Usuario</span>/<span class="unidade_usuario">Adminitração</span></p>

                    <span class="toolinfo">
                        <div style="float:left; width:80px; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="fotos/" border="0" width="80" height="80" style="border-radius:50%;"/></div>
                        <div style="float:right; width:220px;">
                            <p><strong>Nome Teste</strong></p>
                            <p><strong>Usuario</strong></p>
                            <p>Administração</p>
                            <p><i>email@mail.com</i></p>
                            <br/>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Ultima vez online as 12:12 de 12/12/2012</p>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <span class="status off"></span>
            </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Larissa,
Você não chegou a comentar seu código e não sei se você está utilizando (quase com certeza, sim) o framework Bootstrap.

No bootstrap há dois componentes parecidos com o que você quer fazer.

- [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)
- [Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Tenho a impressão de que o que você realmente precisa é do Popover.

Para utilizá-los, você pode executar o seguinte código:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Aqui vai o conteudo do seu popover">
  Popover à esquerda
</button>
```

O código acima, é a maneira mais simples de executar um popover.
Caso você queira mais controle, é possível abri-los manualmente com JQuery:

```
$('#element').popover('show')
```

Enfim, são várias possibilidades para você conseguir construir um popover muito legal. E o mais interessante de tudo, seu popover já é responsivo.

Espero que tenha ajudado, caso contrário, você sempre pode comentar a resposta com suas dúvidas.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela dica Andrew, mas eu não estou usando Bootstrap por algumas incompatibilidades pois eu acabei optando pelo JqueryUI. mas valeu pela dica. Vou postar meu código mais abaixo para algum esclarecimento